# Replace some text in URL inside //

Tags: jquery, regex

Example I have link:

```
var url = "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5MNg6YxqvVA/WEfPc3ZooiI/AAAAAAAAIGU/k54H_HugZbkw9KIo56UjksgiVkX7b-mhACLcB/s540/antipasto-salad-21354_l.jpeg";
```

In link above, you can see `/s504/`.
I want replace every link contains it (always start with `s` and follow with `numbers`).

Example `/s555/`

I used it but it not work: `replace(/^\/s[0-9]/g, "/w500");`

Thank for your help.

Comment: Use `.replace(/\/s[0-9]+\//, '/w500/')`

Comment: What if there are two occurrences of `s`  + 1 or more digits in the string?

Comment: Thank you very much. Link always contains only /s-number/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\/s\d+\/
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DOre86/9)

```js
const regex = /\/s\d+\//mg;
const str = `https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5MNg6YxqvVA/WEfPc3ZooiI/AAAAAAAAIGU/k54H_HugZbkw9KIo56UjksgiVkX7b-mhACLcB/s540/antipasto-salad-21354_l.jpeg`;
const subst = `/w500/`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```